# Parameter in checking item quantity

Tags: magento-1.9, quantity

After daily debugging I'm a little bit confused about some core functionalities in Magento.

In **Item.php** file in **app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/** there is the function 
`checkQuoteItemQty($qty, $summaryQty, $origQty = 0) ...`
 Right above there are some explanations like:

```
/**
 * Checking quote item quantity
 *
 * Second parameter of this method specifies quantity of this product in whole shopping cart
 * which should be checked for stock availability
 *
 * @param mixed $qty quantity of this item (item qty x parent item qty)
 * @param mixed $summaryQty quantity of this product
 * @param mixed $origQty original qty of item (not multiplied on parent item qty)
 * @return Varien_Object
 */
```

Despite reading I am still confused about the `summeryQty` parameter. What exactly does this one? What's the difference between an item and a product in Magento??

If I output this parameter I'll get the value 2. But where does this 2 come from?
This questions belong to an other problem but first I like to understand what this summaryQty parameter is about.

I know, its really theoretically but maybe anyone has a clue whats going on here.